# codeigniter routing index

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

i have a class called comment and inside i have 3 functions called __construct, index and getComments

```
Class comment extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function index($comment_id){
      echo $comment_id;
   }

   public function getComments(){
      //do stuff to get comments and print them to screen
   }
}
```

also in my routes folder i have added a new route

```
$route['comment/(:any)'] = "comment/index/$1";
```

so when i go to mysite.com/comment/123131313123

it **echos** the **comment id** but when i do an ajax call to the getComments() function in the same class it wont work and instead it will show me the word "**getComments**"

how can i make sure that when i go direct to the index function it will show me the parameter and also be able to do ajax calls without having any other problem with the other functions?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you doing the ajax call? What's the URL you're using?

Comment: im using mysite.com/comment/getComments - i have not added the php code i use for the ajax calls becuase its too many... if i remove the index and the route all the ajax calls work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysite.com/comment/getComments` is getting matched to your route

You need to make another route before it which explicitly matches your ajax action

```
$route['comment/getComments'] = "comment/getComments";
$route['comment/(:any)'] = "comment/index/$1";
```

Routes are run in the order they are defined.